# Ensure an async method is never executed in parallel

Tags: node.js, typescript, async-await, promise

There's an async method in some external library, which is not thread-safe (corrupts internal state when being called concurrently) and is very unlikely to be ever fixed in the near future. Yet I want the rest of my codebase to freely use it in any possible parallel vs. sequential combinations (in other words, I want **my** methods that use that method to still be thread-safe).

So I need to wrap that problematic method with some [Active Object](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Active_object) implementation, so that its invocations are always aligned (executed one after another).

My take on this is to use a chain of Promises:

```
var workQueue: Promise<any> = Promise.resolve();

function executeSequentially<T>(action: () => Promise<T>): Promise<T> {

    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {

        workQueue = workQueue.then(() => {
            return action().then(resolve, reject);
        });
    });
}
```

And then instead of directly calling that method:

```
const myPromise = asyncThreadUnsafeMethod(123);
```

I'll be calling it like this:

```
const myPromise = executeSequentially(() => asyncThreadUnsafeMethod(123));
```

But am I missing something? Any potential problems with this approach? Any better ideas?

Comment: Is there the chance of having multiple servers running the same code, like behind a load balancer or using pm2? If there is this chance you'll need some kind of redis setup to mark the troubling process as in progress across servers

Comment: I would be looking at some kind of mutex implementation vs. what you're trying here.  That (as noted by @spirift) would only help if localized to this one server; if it's not multiprocess safe either then you have a bigger problem

Comment: @Joe, the promise returned by executeSequentially() will only be resolved when the passed action completes (or fails). Could be expressed simpler: `function executeSequentially<T>(action: () => Promise<T>): Promise<T> {

    workQueue = workQueue.then(() => action());
    return workQueue;
}
`, but this version would capture the very first exception inside action and stick with it. That's why I'm making a new Promise() out there.

Comment: @spirift, it is an absolutely single-server issue. No need to think of any distributed locks.

Comment: @Joe "*Your `workQueue` promise is always resolved*" - no it's not? `action()` is presumed to return a promise that is not immediately resolved.

Comment: @scale_tone If the concept of a mutex seems unfamiliar to you, think about a FIFO-ordered queue for promises. There are many OSS libraries which implement it already. Then just wrap the problem method in a function that proxies invocations to the queue.

Comment: @jsejcksn Why pull in an extra library when the OP already has implemented the FIFO-ordered queue for promises in 5 lines of code?

Comment: I’m dumb and missed the workqueue assignment.

Comment: @Bergi What if the library is only 2 lines?

Comment: @jsejcksn Then it's hardly worth managing a dependency for that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are no problems with this approach, using a promise queue is a standard pattern that will solve your problem.

While your code does work fine, I would recommend to avoid the [`Promise` constructor antipattern](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23803743/1048572?What-is-the-promise-construction-antipattern-and-how-to-avoid-it):

```
let workQueue: Promise<void> = Promise.resolve();
const ignore = _ => {};
function executeSequentially<T>(action: () => Promise<T>): Promise<T> {
    const result = workQueue.then(action);
    workQueue = result.then(ignore, ignore);
    return result;
}
```

Also you say that you'd be "*calling the method*" like `executeSequentially(() => asyncThreadUnsafeMethod(123));`, but this does leave the potential for mistakes where you forget the `executeSequentially` wrapper and still call the unsafe method directly. Instead I'd recommend to introduce an indirection where you wrap the entire safe call in a function and then export only that, having your codebase only interact with that facade and never with the library itself. To help with the creation of such a facade, I'd curry the `executeSequentially` function:

```
const ignore = _ => {};
function makeSequential<T, A extends unknown[]>(fn: (...args: A) => Promise<T>): (...args: A) => Promise<T> {
    let workQueue: Promise<void> = Promise.resolve();
    return (...args) => {
        const result = workQueue.then(() => fn(...args));
        workQueue = result.then(ignore, ignore);
        return result;
    };
}

export const asyncSafeMethod = makeSequential(asyncThreadUnsafeMethod);
```

or just directly implement it for that one case

```
const ignore = _ => {};
let workQueue: Promise<void> = Promise.resolve();

export function asyncSafeMethod(x: number) {
    const result = workQueue.then(() => asyncThreadUnsafeMethod(x));
    workQueue = result.then(ignore, ignore);
    return result;
}
```

```
import { asyncSafeMethod } from …;

asyncSafeMethod(123);
```

Comment: Thanks @Bergi, that all makes perfect sense!